# best way to reliably persist *small* amount of data?

Tags: java, persistence

I have a system, written in java, that until now has not needed to persist any data previously.  We now have a new requirment that appears to require persisting data, but only a small amount on rare occasions.

I'm trying to figure out the ideal method to persist this data with a farily decent (doesn't have to 100% if it's 99.9 percent) effective method to ensue we don't lose data.

The obvious idea is a DB, but for so little data adding a depenency on a DB seems over-kill.  The next idea is to writing to a file, but how does one handle lacking permissions to write to the file, or the file being corrupted, or datarace/staleness issues?  Is the simple/obvious approch to persistence with a file sufficent or is it likely to cause issues in the real-world?

in short, what are some effective, but not too draconian, methods to reliably persist data with a high, if not perfect, degree of confidence that it will work even if the system goes down unexpectedly?  Is trivialy implemented file-persistence without anything fancy sufficent?  are there any useful classes that will assist with this?

Comment: Your question is very opinion based and you're leaving much room for speculation in your question: How important is the data? Is there a risk that there will not be enough permissions? How would you like to handle the data corruption issues? (We really can't decide for you, it's not our project).

Comment: On a side note, as you ask for "classes that will assist with this" I can highly recommend the Jackson Library. That will give you any POJO you would like into a JSON string. Then it's up to you to decide where to store that string. Of course, if you're afraid of manual data manipulation, you could consider encrypting the JSON data using AES-128.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to save/persist Objects, take a look to the ObjectOutputStream class. Itd a good and fast way to serialize/persist data from a Object.

But notice: every Object u want to "save", needs to implement the interface "Serializeable" to be used with ObjectOutputStream.

Here is a good Tut: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm
And here is the doc from oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

Answer (score 1):

If the data to be persisted is a boolean flag, then you could create or delete a file with a known name to serve as a boolean flag.

If the amount of data to be persisted is small enough, then you could persist it by creating a zero-length file (or a directory) with the data as part of the filename. Creating a file is an atomic operation from the application's viewpoint. A shortcoming of this method is that you may have to read the directory to find the persistence file, instead of accessing a file with a known name.

If you're using Java 7 on a system with symbolic links, you can create a symbolic link with the data to be persisted as the target of the symlink. Creating a symlink is an atomic operation as well, and it's not an error to create a symlink which points to a nonexistent file.

If you decide to store the persistence data in the conventional way as the contents of a file, the usual way to write out the file is as follows:

1. Open a new file for writing. Create the file in the correct directory but using a temporary name that would be ignored by your application.
2. Write your data to the file, then close it. Catch any errors at this point and don't proceed if the write operations or the close failed.
3. Rename the file to have the correct name.

This process gives you some assurance that the persistence file will only be stored under its correct name if its contents are complete and correct. If you are replacing an old persistence file with a new one, leave it in place until step 3. The rename operation will atomically (in one operation) replace the old file with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If it's simple key-value information a properties file might be enough.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("key", "value");
//to save it:
prop.store(new FileOutputStream("filename.properties"), null);
//to load it:
prop.load(new FileInputStream("filename.properties"));
```

It's certainly easy enough.